# Не работает regex Java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть следующий код, который ищет в указанном файле строчку `Apples = цифра` и при нахождении устанавливать нужное значение:

```
package com.company;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
/**
 * Created by zn_am on 14.03.16.
 */
    public class searchf {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            String fileName = "D:\\com.company\\shared\\JsonData.xml";
            String search = "(Apples = (\\d+))";
            String replace = "Apples = 5555";
            Charset charset = StandardCharsets.US_ASCII;
            Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
            Files.write(path,
                    new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset).replace(search, replace)
                            .getBytes(charset));
        }
    }
```

Но значение не меняется. Почему?

Comment: А проверяли отдельно String(____).replace(___)? Он выводит новую стрингу?

Comment: Не понял что вы имеете ввиду.

Comment: Добавьте System.out.println(new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset).replace(search, replace)); Если там правленьые данные, значит проблема в записи. Если нет то проблема в самом поиске и замене.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вам нужен метод `replaceAll`, а не `replace`. Метод `replace` заменяет вхождения `CharSequence` и не умеет работать с регулярными выражениями, в то время как `replaceAll` умеет и это именно то, что вам нужно.